# How to add analytics for Google Play In-App Reviews API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services

we are using Google Play In-App Reviews API in app to rate application after some scenarios, but I have still some unclear question, and can't get answers from documentation.

1. Is there any way to understand window was displayed or not at all ? (reason-analytics)
2. Is there any way to understand user rated application or not?(reason-analytics)
3. Is there any way to understand if user rated application with 5 star previously ?(reason- follow best practice, as they [documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#when-to-request))

```html
try {
                val result = reviewManager.launchReview(
                    activityWeak.get(),
                    reviewManager.requestReview()
                )
                prefs.lastRatingRequestDate = Calendar.getInstance().time.dateToString()
                Result.success(result)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
                Result.failure(e)
            }
```

as far as I understand answer is 'no' for all my questions
[image]

Comment: Were you able to get an answer to the above questions?